# Avast reported that my android app is a Android:Evo-gen [Trj]

Tags: android, android-studio

I started learning android and I'm learning from the book Head First Android Development. In each chapter, a small android application is created there. I have written several such applications and run them in the Genymotion emulator. All of them started without problems. I then decided to run these apps on my Honor 8X device using Android Studio. They also started without problems. But after a while, I run each of these already installed apps on my smartphone and Avast informs me that all these apps are infected. I checked the .apk files of these apps are on Virustotal and it informed me that the files contain Android virus: Evo-gen [Trj]. How could there be a virus, if at first everything started without problems? I'm sure my apps don't contain malicious code.

https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/d12c7096e7502ea67f84af58d447c2f881eba41da0bffa8de5d305a8dfc726d6/detection

Comment: How did you resolve the issue? I am facing the same.

Comment: I haven't done this app for a while. Then I decided to rewrite it to Kotlin and created a completely new project in Android Studio. And in the new project, this problem did not arise. I don't know what it was.

Comment: Is it possible to upload the source code of a simple proof of concept app that has the issue to GitHub or similar?

Answer (score 1):

I can reassure you. This is an Avast problem with the heuristic process.

I had the same problem and have it again with two applications. These are reported as EVO-GEN

You need to contact Avast. There is an Avast website that they can use to report this issue. Then send the app to Avast. The signature is then taken from the database.

https://www.avast.com/de-de/false-positive-file-form.php#android

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that In my phone. The superintendent of police here installed hacking app in my phone and it is one of them. I haven't intentionally remov d it for evidence. To be on the safe side get it rooted and use VPN security or Bitdefender antivirus free.